# Orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$

Tags: orthonormal

It is well-known that the Hermite functions form an orthonormal basis for  $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Is there an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$?

Thanks.

Comment: How about the $H_m(x)H_n(y)H_p(z)$?

Comment: Hi @LordSharktheUnknown sorry my functional analysis is a bit rusty. Can you remind me of the justification of this?

Comment: The integral for orthogonality factorizes across the three variables, so you end up with an orthonormal basis. In fact the same argument applies to extend any orthonormal basis from $L^2(\mathbb R)$ to $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Thank you. So, would the basis expansion be something like: $f(x,y,z) = c1 Hm Hn Hp + c2 Hm Hn Hp ...$

Comment: It would be like $c_{1,1,1}H_1(x_1)H_1(x_2)H_1(x_3)+\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration of the comment left by L. S. the Unknown

Given any orthonormal basis $\{\phi_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, we can form an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ simply by taking products of the basis vectors like this:
$$
\phi_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\phi_{i_1}(x_1)\phi_{i_2}(x_2)\cdots\phi_{i_n}(x_n).
$$
The reason it works is because
$$
\bigl\langle\phi_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),\phi_{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_n}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\bigr\rangle=\prod_{k=1}^n\langle \phi_{i_k},\phi_{j_k}\rangle,
$$
which equals $1$ if and only if $i_k=j_k$ for all $k$, and otherwise equals $0$ - the defining property of an orthonormal basis.